# Calculating the essential matrix from two sets of corresponding points

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, 3d-reconstruction

I'm trying to reconstruct a 3d image from two calibrated cameras. One of the steps involved is to calculate the 3x3 essential matrix `E`, from two sets of corresponding (homogeneous) points (more than the 8 required) `P_a_orig` and `P_b_orig` and the two camera's 3x3 internal calibration matrices `K_a` and `K_b`.

We start off by normalizing our points with

```
P_a = inv(K_a) * p_a_orig
```

and

```
P_b = inv(K_b) * p_b_orig
```

We also know the constraint

```
P_b' * E * P_a = 0
```

I'm following it this far, but how do you actually solve that last problem, e.g. finding the nine values of the `E` matrix? I've read several different lecture notes on this subject, but they all leave out that crucial last step. Likely because it is supposedly trivial math, but I can't remember when I last did this and I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

This equation is actually pretty common in geometry algorithms, essentially, you are trying to calculate the matrix ***X*** from the equation ***AXB=0***. To solve this, you vectorise the equation, which means, 
[image]

vec() means vectorised form of a matrix, i.e., simply stack the coloumns of the matrix one over the another to produce a single coloumn vector. If you don't know the meaning of the scary looking symbol, its called Kronecker product and you can read it from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), its easy, trust me :-)

Now, say I call the matrix obtained by Kronecker product of ***B^T*** and ***A*** as ***C***. 
Then, ***vec(X)*** is the null vector of the matrix ***C*** and the way to obtain that is by doing the [SVD decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of ***C^TC*** (C transpose multiplied by C) and take the the last coloumn of the matrix ***V***. This last coloumn is nothing but your ***vec(X)***. Reshape X to 3 by 3 matrix. This is you Essential matrix.

In case you find this maths too daunting to code, simply use the following code by  Y.Ma et.al:

```
%  p are homogenius coordinates of the first image of size 3 by n
%  q are homogenius coordinates of the second image of size 3 by n

function [E]  = essentialDiscrete(p,q)

n = size(p);
NPOINTS = n(2);

% set up matrix A such that A*[v1,v2,v3,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6]' = 0
A = zeros(NPOINTS, 9);

if NPOINTS < 9
     error('Too few mesurements')
     return;
end

for i = 1:NPOINTS
  A(i,:) = kron(p(:,i),q(:,i))';
end
r = rank(A);

if r < 8 
  warning('Measurement matrix rank defficient')
  T0 = 0; R = [];
end;

[U,S,V] = svd(A);

% pick the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue
e = V(:,9);
e = (round(1.0e+10*e))*(1.0e-10);
% essential matrix 
E = reshape(e, 3, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things:

- The Essential matrix can be estimated using the [8-point algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-point_algorithm), which you can implement yourself.
- You can use the `estimateFundamentalMatrix` function from the Computer Vision System Toolbox, and then get the Essential matrix from the Fundamental matrix.
- Alternatively, you can calibrate your stereo camera system using the [estimateCameraParameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-vision.html) function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox, which will compute the Essential matrix for you.

Comment: are you sure one can simply obtain the essential matrix from the fundamental matrix? I believe this is not directly possible, without the knowledge of the intrinsic camera paramters...